# Парсинг Json; Запись данных в ветку TreeView

Tags: c#, json, парсер, treeview

Я имею большой [json](/questions/tagged/json) файл, в котором данные расположены так:

- **id** - id элемента
- **parent** - id родителя
- **name** - Имя

  ...
  {
  id: "2859",
  parent: "5853",
  name: " г. Москва"
  },
  ...

Мне это нужно кинуть в TreeView.
Помогите пожалуйста =(

Сейчас делаю это так:

```
...
private void getRegions()
    {
        var content = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1251) }.DownloadString("https://www.bicotender.ru/ajax/regiontree/?isSite=0");
        RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);

        foreach (var _data in data.data)
        {
            bool find = false;

            foreach(TreeNode n in Regions.Nodes)
            {
                if (n.Name == _data.parent)
                {
                    bool find2 = false;
                    n.Nodes.Add(_data.id, _data.name);
                    find = true;
                }
            }

            if (find != true)
            {
                Regions.Nodes.Add(_data.id, _data.name);
            }

        }
    }

...

public class Datum
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string parent { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

Но, он делает это так:
 [image: TreeView]

[Сам файл Json](https://www.bicotender.ru/ajax/regiontree/)

Comment: Приведите ваш класс `RootObject`.

Comment: Сделал правку поста, вставил туда этот класс

Comment: А у всех элементов есть parent?

Comment: Да, у всех элементов есть parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы ищете родителя среди уже добавленных элементов, а они могут быть и позже.

Давайте для начала составим древовидную структуру. Для этого поменяем класс на такой:

```
public class Datum
{
    public int id { get; set; }     // <-- поменял на int
    public int parent { get; set; } // <-- поменял на int
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> children;    // <-- добавил
}
```

Поле `children` не будет заполняться при чтении из JSON, но мы воспользуемся им потом.

Теперь, организуем наши элементы в дерево. И заодно вычислим *корни* — те элементы, у которых нет предков.

```
RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
var list = data.data;
Dictionary<int, Datum> byId = list.ToDictionary(d => d.id);
List<Datum> roots = new List<Datum>();
// gather children
foreach (var datum in list)
{
    if (byId.TryGetValue(datum.parent, out Datum parent))
    {
        if (parent.children == null)
            parent.children = new List<Datum>();
        parent.children.Add(datum);
    }
    else
    {
        roots.Add(datum);
    }
}
```

Теперь наше заполнение выглядит как-то так:

```
FillRec(Regions.Nodes, roots);
```

```
void FillRec(TreeNodeCollection collection, List<Datum> content)
{
    foreach (var datum in content)
    {
        var child = collection.Add(datum.id.ToString(), datum.name);
        if (datum.children != null)
            FillRec(child.Nodes, datum.children);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ругается на эту строку:
  if (byId.TryGetValue(datum.parent, out Datum parent))

Вернее непосредственно на Datum parent.

Если его объявить отдельно (Datum parent;). То ошибка исчезает, но код не работает.

Comment: @АлексейАцкий: Хм, а в каком смысле не работает? Или вы разобрались, в чём проблема?

Comment: Скорее нет чем да(

Comment: @АлексейАцкий: Окей, сейчас доберусь до компьютера и исправлю

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @АлексейАцкий: Пробуйте! Обновил ответ.