# Парсинг JSON в TreeView

Tags: c#, json, treeview

Находил схожий [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745201/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-json-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-treeview), но в нем рассматривается зависимость по **id**. У меня же стоит задача парсинга такого файла.

```
[
   {
      "Name":"Пикова Екатерина Львовна"
   },
   {
      "Name":"1 отдел",
      "Childs":[
         {
            "Name":"Петров Петр Петрович"
         },
         {
            "Name":"1 кабинет",
            "Childs":[
               {
                  "Name":"Иванов Иван Иванович"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"2 отдел",
      "Childs":[
         {
            "Name":"Антонов Антон Антонович"
         },
         {
            "Name":"1 кабинет",
            "Childs":[
               {
                  "Name":"Егоров Егор Егорович"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "Name":"2 кабинет",
            "Childs":[
               {
                  "Name":"Сергеев Сергей Сергеевич"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "Name":"3 кабинет",
            "Childs":[
               {
                  "Name":"Алексеев Алексей Алексеевич"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"3 отдел",
      "Childs":[
         {
            "Name":"Петухов Андрей Ринатович"
         },
         {
            "Name":"1 кабинет",
            "Childs":[
               {
                  "Name":"Егоров Егор Егорович"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "Name":"4 кабинет",
            "Childs":[
               {
                  "Name":"Арахисов Игорь Сергеевич"
               },
               {
                  "Name":"Ульянов Владимир Ильич"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "Name":"4 отдел",
      "Childs":[
         {
            "Name":"Сахаров Андрей Дмитриевич"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

И попытка уложить его в **TreeView**, а после, что немаловажно, это укладка **TreeView** обратно в **JSON**.

Пробовал парсить его через класс:

```
    public class Structure
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Childs { get; set; }
    }
```

Но понял, что этот класс в корне неверен. Прошу помочь разобраться с этим.

UPD: За неимением лучшего варианта, было принято решение добавить в каждый узел хотя бы пустой объект "Childs": []

Теперь парсится это всё кодом:

```
var json = JToken.Parse(readText);
var structures = json.ToObject<Structure[]>();
for(int i = 0; i < structures.Length; i++)
{
    person_tree.Nodes.Add(structures[i].Name);
    if(structures[i].Childs.Length > 0)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < structures[i].Childs.Length; j++)
        {
            person_tree.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(structures[i].Childs[j].Name);
            if(structures[i].Childs[j].Childs.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int q = 0; q < structures[i].Childs[j].Childs.Length; q++)
                {
                    person_tree.Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Nodes.Add(structures[i].Childs[j].Childs[q].Name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Но это действует только для глубины не более трех, а хочется рекурсию.

UPD2:

Для обратного парсинга, с учетом ответа KuzCode, пытаюсь написать

```
public Structure[] TreeNodeToStructure(TreeNode[] trees)
{
    var structure = new List<Structure>();

    foreach(var node in trees)
    {
        var str = new Structure();
        str.Name = node.Name;
        str.Childs = TreeNodeToStructure(node.Nodes);

        structure.Add(str);
    }
    return structure.ToArray();
}
```

Но это явно делается не так

Comment: предположу, что достаточно изменить тип свойства `Childs` из `string` на `Structure[]`, но не до конца уверен в том, что этого достаточно

Comment: да, всё верно, я был прав

Comment: @KuzCode, согласен, структура теперь работоспособна, благодарю, осталась прямая и обратная укладка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Токен `Childs` в вашем `json`-е является самоподобным массивом, по-этому ему точно соответствует не тип `string`, а тип `IEnumerable<Structure>` или любой его наследник, массив, например.

Следует изменить класс `Structure` так:

```
public class Structure
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Structure[] Childs { get; set; }
}
```

Тогда десериализация будет выглядеть так:

```
var jsonString = "ваш json";
var json       = JToken.Parse(jsonString);
var structures = json.ToObject<Structure[]>();
```

**UPD:**
Чтобы превратить массив `Structure` в массив `TreeNode` необходимо использовать рекурсию:

```
public TreeNode[] StructuresToTreeNodes(Structure[] structures)
{
    if (structures is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(structures));

    var nodes = new List<TreeNode>();

    foreach (var structure in structures)
    {
        var node = new TreeNode(structure.Name);

        if (structure.Childs != null && structure.Childs.Length > 0)
            node.Nodes.AddRange(StructuresToTreeNodes(structure.Childs));

        nodes.Add(node);
    }

    return nodes.ToArray();
}
```

Использовать так:

```
personTreeView.Nodes.AddRange(StructuresToTreeNodes(structures));
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD2:**

```
public Structure[] TreeNodesToStructures(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    if (nodes is null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nodes));

    var structures = new List<Structure>();

    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        var structure = new Structure() { Name = node.Text };

        if (node.Nodes != null && node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            structure.Childs = TreeNodesToStructures(node.Nodes);

        structures.Add(structure);
    }

    return structures.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: А способа укладки в TreeView нет случайно?

Comment: это ж вроде элементарно, сейчас поробую

Comment: @Anton обновил ответ

Comment: Пытался по твоему образу и подобию выполнить обратную сериализацию в JSON: дошел до
        public Structure[] TreeNodeToStructure(TreeNode[] treeNodes)
        {
            var structure = new List<Structure>();

            foreach(var node in treeNodes)
            {
                var structa = new Structure(node.Text); 
            }
        }
И я кончился

Comment: Так там же код 1 в 1 получится, только вместо `node` - `structure` и вместо `node.Nodes.Add` `structure.Childs =`

Comment: Не смог по Вашим советам сделать, попытку выложил выше

Comment: @Anton обновил ответ, можете ставить галочку